# Ajax - How to provide data to a child JSP via a parent JSP and reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out the best way to address my issue. What I'm trying to do is utilize an existing JSP partial (child) into another JSP page (parent). (These pages are driven by Java Controller classes in a Weblogic 12c environment using Spring.) The child JSP contains a data table that is built off of a list supplied by its current Java Controller. (The model attribute is called claimList.) The first thing I tried doing was including the child into the parent this way:

```
<jsp:include page="../../jsp/claimSummary.jsp"/>
```

In the parent JSP, there is an included JS file that contains a function that builds the same exact data that the claimList attribute for the child JSP needs. This method is executed on load.

Included JS file for parent JSP:

```
function parent() {};
var claimList = [];

$(function() {
    parent.buildClaimList();
};

parent.prototype.buildClaimList = function() {
    var fileNumber = $("#sidebar_primary_fileNumber").text();

    //request all the claims
    $.ajax({
        url: contextPath + "/getClaimList",
        type: "POST",
        data: {fileNumber: fileNumber},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (claims) {
            if (claims.success) {
                if (claims.data.length > 0) {
                    // Sort by claim date.
                    claims.data.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return new Date(a.claimDateDt) < new Date(b.claimDateDt);
                    });

                    claimList = claims.data;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $('#claim-summary-table').load("../../../WEB-INF/jsp/claimSummary.jsp", function() {});
    return true;
};
```

I tried making the list available by making the claimList local variable in the parent JS file... that didn't translate to the child JSP, not surprisingly. Also, at the end of the *buildClaimList* function, I am attempting to reload the child JSP with the updated claimList data, which also isn't working, but I don't know why.

So, the child JSP does not reload, and the data table is never populated with data. I was trying to make the least amount of changes possible to get this child JSP to work in the parent, by changing mainly the parent JSP and/or JS file. Is there any way I can get the local variable claimList to be recognized by the child JSP the same as it would have access to the claimList attribute from the controller model? And what would be the best method to refresh that JSP to get it to show the data gathered from the Ajax call without reloading the parent page?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see you tried to access WEB-INF folder from the client. This should not work since this folder is only accessible from the server (JSP/Servlet)

Comment: @AxelH Makes sense, but the intention was to reload the child JSP partial. Would there be a way to reload it via an Ajax call from the client, after having built the claimList?

Comment: Calling a servlet/ws that will forwards the request to the JSP ? How are you calling the parent JSP in your example ? And where is it stored =

Comment: @AxelH The pages are deployed on a Weblogic 12c server cluster and the workflow of the web app is managed by custom Controller objects. There is currently a controller that handles the request for the child JSP and produces the data it needs to populate the dataTable in that page. I was basically wanting to graft that page into a navigation menu dropdown on the parent page, but I confess I can't seem to find the right controller that produces the parent page. (The parent JSP _is_ the navigation bar for the app.)

Comment: Well, you just need to configure whatever is your controller to send you back the claimSummary.jsp file. This is the same as for the parent, a path linked to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Compose the data `claimList` into an html table data and fill the data in the table.

```
var tableData = {some processing of claimList}
```

Now use this tableData variable and update `$('#claim-summary-table')`

```
$('#claim-summary-table').html(tableData);
```

Comment: I need the child JSP to execute its own Javascript components when included in the parent. My issue is that I do not know how to give it the request parameter the controller needs to be able to generate the data table in the child JSP with the appropriate data. This way seems like it would be a rewrite of the existing JSP by writing the table programmatically in Javascript. That looks like it would be a major rewrite, and my experience is more on the Java side than UI / Javascript side, unfortunately.